# How can I remove blueprints from my inventory in "Dust: An Elysian Tail" that doesn't cost me money?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

I've been accumulating [blueprints](http://elysiantail.wikia.com/wiki/Blueprints) and they have begun to clutter my inventory.  I'd like to get rid of them, but crafting them costs me the crafting materials plus the value of the item.  Is there some way to get rid of blueprints that I have missed?

Comment: Which platform are you playing this on? PC, Linux, Mac, Xbox, or PS4?

Comment: I'm playing on PC.

Comment: On PC, I believe hovering over the blueprint and hitting the C key gets rid of it... Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to press the "C" key to discard any unused blueprints. Though keeping them in your inventory shouldn't hinder your game at all either.